# How do we know PDO is escaping SQL Injections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I am newbie with PDO libraries. I am working on development environment with mysql as my database. I am able to run through my queries using prepare and execute function while using "?" placeholder and also bindParam method while using named placeholders (ex: ":column").

After this I tried to see if PDO does any kind of escaping by putting in any quotes to sanitize the query like mysql_real_escape_string does. I am trying to see what would the query look but all I get is the statement that has been passed into the prepare statement, but not the query that would be executed.

I tried to var_dump the $result->execute(), and $result->fetch() but the execute statement gives me my prepare statement's sql with place holders while fetch statement gives me the result of that query.

Is there a way to look at the find query that would be run, or atleast how the parameters would look before running the query??

I hope I am clear with my question. :|

Comment: You worry too much. Prepared statements escape your input at 100%. If you need to see what the final query looks like, you have to setup a database query log.

Comment: @netcoder Prepared statements do not escape anything (unless in compatible mode). And there is nothing new in the query log

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Well technically yes it does, although you can word it the way you want. As for "there is nothing new in the query log", I simply don't understand what that means...

Comment: @netcoder Nope, it doesn't. Technically or literally or whatever. There is a link down below on how prepared statements works, you'd find it very enlightening. Please do not comment until you learn it carefully and tried to run the code from it

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: This is a PDO question, and yes prepared statements in PDO escapes the input. Please do not comment until you learn some diplomacy.

Comment: @netcoder I hate diplomacy when I meet ignorance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write something like:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = :col_name;');
$stmt->bindValue('col_name', 'some \' value');
$stmt->execute();
```

The actual query is... `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name = :col_name;`. That's called *prepared statement*. Firstly, you send query to the database, later you send query parameters. PDO doesn't merge query and parameters.

You've probably thought that `PDOStatement::bindValue()` does something like:

```
public function bindValue($placeholer, $value, $valueType = PDO::PARAM_STR) {
    $this->query = str_replace($placeholder, $this->quote($value, $valueType), $this->query);
}
```

But it **doesn't**.

It does something more like that:

```
public function execute() {
    try {
        $this->sendQueryToDatabase($this->query);

        // Query is valid
        $this->sendParametersToDatabase($this->parameters);

        return $this->fetchResultSet();
    } catch (... $e) {
        // Query is invalid (eg. syntax error)
        throw ...;
    }
}
```

[Read more about Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html)

Comment: so how would we know if the parameters being sent are safe?? do we need to check them before hand???

Comment: Parameters cannot be unsafe as they aren't part of the query. They're just a raw data.

Comment: hey I know it might a bit too high level, do you have any idea about how the query would be parsed and then how would these parameters be sent/substituted with placeholders?

Comment: Query and its parameters are sent separately and I guess they're never merged (you'll have to study MySQL sources to know how it exactly works). Even if some parameter contains `' OR do badCode --` it will be treated as a **raw text** and such value will be inserted into column.

Comment: if the parameter as you said 'Or do badcode '-- is passed, it would hurt the database right?? since no escaping would be done?

Comment: Not if it's being processed as raw text as the database will never try to parse the parameter a query. It's basically like how `$var = 'system("ls");';` doesn't actually evaluate the php code in $var. It's just data=

Comment: Alright! Thank you all for being patient and explaining this.

Answer (score 3):

To put it straight.

PDO has 2 modes of running prepared statements:

1. Native mode. Query and data being sent to the database **se-pa-ra-te-ly**. Which means that data **never** being added to the query. So, no harm could be done. Ever. The query being sent to the database as is, with `?` marks (but no named placeholders which being replaced by PDO with `?`s)
2. Compatibility mode. PDO do make an old-style query, by substituting placeholders with binded variables depends on variable name. Strings being quoted/escaped, the rest being cast to it's type.

Both methods are perfectly safe.

The real danger begins when you have a variable *identifier*...

Comment: why is variable identifier dangerous?? I thought it was more safe since we even verify the data type?

Comment: @macha I mean a field name. For example `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $column_name` is indeed dangerous

Answer (score 1):

the prepare statement is handle by mysql, so pdo don't escape the request, 
pdo send the request and "after" the parameter

Comment: Don't know why you are getting downvoted, this is actually true.

Comment: This is not actually true, PDO usually emulates the prepared statements, as server-side prepared statements, while supported, are not generally a good idea.

Comment: Server-side prepared statements are bad; they generally result in worse performance and less robustness, but you might find otherwise. But that's OK, PDO doesn't need to use them, the emulation is a good thing.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the mangled language makes it impossible for me to understand what the poster is saying, despite the fact that I understand how prepared statements work.

Answer (score -1):

Enable the general query log, and watch the queries actually being executed against the server when you're running simple statements - do some inserts, for example, with strings containing embedded quotes or nuls.